# Animation...why is it being added to my objects

Tags: animation

Everytime I Duplicate an object, scale an object it apparently adds a key Frame to my object. I have no idea why. I am not doing any animation nor ever have.
I can delete the animation key frame by menu option in Object Mode: Object/animation/ClearKeyFrames.
Can't find any setting that I may have accidently changed.
Assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using the default Layout workspace which has a timeline below the 3D workspace?  If you are, it's possible that you accidently clicked the white circle in the timeline header that means 'automatically generate keyframes'.  Try clicking it once to see if the problem stops.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I closed the timeline space in the 3D workspace as I don't do any animation. However, just opened and noted that the white circle was actually highlighted. Turned it off and now OK. Don't understand why is was highlighted. Is there a shortcut that I may have used in error ?. Thanks

Comment: No shortcut that I know of, but it's something that people sometimes accidentally click without noticing.